# robot_localization does not produce odom->base_link transform

Tags: ros, navigation, tf-broadcaster, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I have been searching for a long time for my problem but still have not found a solution. I am using robot_localization with IMU data. My imu data is published to a topic `/inertial_data` with `frame_id = "imu"`. The following is my configuration file

```
frequency: 30

sensor_timeout: 0.1

transform_time_offset: 0.0

two_d_mode: false

print_diagnostics: true

debug: false
debug_out_file: /home/mohak/catkin_ws/debug_file.txt

map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base
world_frame: odom

use_control: true
stamped_control: false
control_timeout: 0.2
control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

imu0: /inertial_data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false,  false,  false,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_nodelay: false

imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8
imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8
imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8

process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0.05, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0.06, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0.03, 0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.06, 0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.025, 0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0.025, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0.04, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0.02, 0,    0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,    0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.01, 0,
                           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0.015]

initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9, 0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    1e-9,  0,     0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     1e-9,  0,     0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     1e-9,  0,    0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     1e-9, 0,    0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    1e-9, 0,
                              0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,     0,     0,     0,    0,    1e-9]
```

I am also publishing the transform between `base_link` and `imu` via a ß`static_transform_publisher`. On running the `ekf_localization_node` the odometry/filered topic displays the odometry messages with `frame_id` as `odom` and `child_frame_id` as `"base"` but the trasform tree does not show the appropriate transform as being published. The transform tree only shows the transform being published between imu and base and that too by ekf_se and not the static_transform_publisher. The transform tree is imu->base and odom is shown as a floating frame not connected to either.

EDIT:
This is the tf tree published when I run the entire system:
[http://imgur.com/CPAxgOx](https://imgur.com/CPAxgOx)

My robot_localization launch file is included from another launch file in a package called data_publisher. I am including both of the files here:

http://www.filedropper.com/datapublisher_1

http://www.filedropper.com/ekfimu

Thanks for the help in advance and sorry if it is too confusing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239198/robot_localization-does-not-produce-odom-%3Ebase_link-transform/) by [mohakbhardwaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25043/mohakbhardwaj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-13**:
Can you post a tf tree of the frames you've got?
There are several things that I suspect might be wrong like running static_transform_publisher that broadcasts the imu->base which is obviously wrong or even base_link_frame which is "base"... but first post that tf tree!

**Comment by [mohakbhardwaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25043/mohakbhardwaj/) on 2016-07-13**:
@Arwen I have edited the answer to include an image of the tf tree. It shows the odom frame being published as not connected to any other frame but as a floating frame. The static transform publisher is used to publish the transform from the location where the imu is mounted on the system to the bas

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-13**:
It's a little spooky... your robot_localization parameters seem fine but it's strange that the tf tree shows that `imu` -> `base` is being broadcast by ekf_se, you may wanna post your robot_localization launch file and exact line you're using for running static_transform_publisher.

**Comment by [mohakbhardwaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25043/mohakbhardwaj/) on 2016-07-13**:
@Arwen: Yes that seems very unnatural to me as well. I have included links the launch files in my original post now. I have a data_publisher package which has the responsibility of publishing the imu data (only rotation rates and linear accelerations in my case) as a sensor_msgs/Imu message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the information you've provided now I can help you solve your problem.

The `ekf_localization_node` that you run provides the transformation between `odom` and `base`, the `static_transform_publisher` instance also broadcasts transformation between `imu` and `base`. So this will be the result:

`odom` -> `base`
, `imu` -> `base`

while the correct tf tree must be like this:

`odom` -> `base` -> `imu`

Your base frame has two parents which is clearly not possible. Each frame can only have one parent.

In your case, you are running `static_transform_publisher` with wrong input parameters.

```
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_to_robot_base" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 $(arg imu_frame_id) base 100" />
```

Just switch the parent and child frame in the input arguments and your problem should be solved. The result must be like this:

```
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="imu_to_robot_base" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base $(arg imu_frame_id) 100" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) with karma: 146 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohakbhardwaj](https://answers.ros.org/users/25043/mohakbhardwaj/) on 2016-07-14**:
Thanks! It is now publishing the transform. I have one confusion thought, is there anything in the parameters file that I am missing for the robot_localization package to compute x,y,z position from the rates and accelerations only? It is constantly publishing the x,y,z position as zero

**Comment by [Arwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/10946/arwen/) on 2016-07-15**:
@mohakbhardwaj: I think you should start with a simpler configuration, currently you have set several advanced parameters and finding the exact problem is not that easy. By the way I haven't tested robot_localization with only a single imu, but I don't think the result would be satisfying.